# VBA For Loop Where Each Answer must = True

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, if-statement, vba

I have a VBA macro I'm working on that has several loops running.

Where I'm stuck, however, is that I want the macro to go through all m's and if all are True, then move on to the next set of code. If any one is false, then I want it to go to the next For loop within which this is embedded.

```
         For m = 2 To 29
            If Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(contentrownum, contentcolnum) = False And _
            (Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(keywordrownum, m) = Worksheets("Product Categorization").Cells(productrownum, (m + 1)) Or _
            Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(keywordrownum, m) = "All") Then Next m
```

Above is the specific piece of code that I want to identify whether, for each m, the conditions mentioned are False. If any are False, then it should move on to the next j in the outer loop.

Below is the full loop code if needed.

Full Code:

```
'outer loops through each ASIN (i)
 For Each i In Worksheets("Background Search Term Analysis").Range("B5", Worksheets("Background Search Term Analysis").Cells(LastRow, 2)).Cells
    contentrownum = Application.Match(i, Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Range("B1", Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(LastRow, 2)).Cells, 0)
    productrownum = Application.Match(i, Worksheets("Product Categorization").Range("A1", Worksheets("Product Categorization").Cells(LastRow, 1)).Cells, 0)

    'inner loops through each keyword (j)
    For Each j In Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Range("M2", Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(2, LastColumn)).Cells
        contentcolnum = Application.Match(j, Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Range("A2", Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(2, LastColumn)).Cells, 0)
        keywordrownum = Application.Match(j, Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Range("A1", Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(LastKeywordRow, 1)).Cells, 0)

        'prints the current values for each variable as the loop progresses
        'end values should match printed last row and column; helps identify where breaks occur
        Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(1, 4).Value = contentrownum
        Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(1, 5).Value = productrownum
        Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(1, 6).Value = contentcolnum
        Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(1, 7).Value = keywordrownum

       'if this product doesn't currently have the keyword (j) in it and the keyword tags match the product tags then
       For m = 2 To 29
        If Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(contentrownum, contentcolnum) = False And _
        (Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(keywordrownum, m) = Worksheets("Product Categorization").Cells(productrownum, (m + 1)) Or _
        Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(keywordrownum, m) = "All") Then Next m 

        'if all of m loop are True, then move on to this step; if any m is False, then move on to next j
        WrdArray() = Split(j)
            For k = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
                If InStr(LCase(result_no_dup), LCase(WrdArray(k))) = 0 _
                And InStr(LCase(Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(contentrownum, 12).Value), LCase(WrdArray(k))) = 0 Then
                    result_no_dup_compact = result_no_dup_compact & WrdArray(k)
                    If Len(result_no_dup_compact) > Worksheets("Instructions").Range("B4").Value Then Exit For
                    result_no_dup = result_no_dup & " " & WrdArray(k)
                End If
            Next k
            result_no_spaces = result & j
            If Len(result_no_spaces) > Worksheets("Instructions").Range("B4").Value Then Exit For
            'if true and character limit not exceeded, add the keyword (j) to our result concatentation
            result = result & " " & j
            'if true and character limit not exceeded, add the keyword (j) to our results concatenation with commas
            result_commas = result_commas & ", " & j
        End If
    Next j

   'once i go through all of my keywords, set ASIN background search term cell value equal to result
   Worksheets("Background Search Term Analysis").Cells(contentrownum, 4).Value = Right(result, Len(result) - 1)
   Worksheets("Background Search Term Analysis").Cells(contentrownum, 5).Value = Right(result_commas, Len(result_commas) - 2)
   Worksheets("Background Search Term Analysis").Cells(contentrownum, 6).Value = Right(result_no_dup, Len(result_no_dup) - 1)
   'reset results to empty for next ASIN (i)
   result = ""
   result_no_spaces = ""
   result_commas = ""
   result_no_dup = ""
   result_no_dup_compact = ""
Next i
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Consider moving functional blocks of your code into functions or subroutines. It would make debugging and maintaining far easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find an *m* condition that doesn't match, Exit For. The value of *m* will be <=29. It will only be >29 if *m* has looped successfully through 2 to 29 because the last Next m increments *m* to 30 and that's when it exits the For m = 2 To 29 loop.

```
' ...
'inner loops through each keyword (j)
For Each j In Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Range("M2", Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(2, LastColumn)).Cells
    ' ...
   'if this product doesn't currently have the keyword (j) in it and the keyword tags match the product tags then
   For m = 2 To 29
       If cbool(Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(contentrownum, contentcolnum)) then
           exit for
       elseif Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(keywordrownum, m) <> Worksheets("Product Categorization").Cells(productrownum, (m + 1)) and _
              Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(keywordrownum, m) <> "All") then
           exit for
       end if
   Next m 

    'if all of m loop are True, then move on to this step; if any m is False, then move on to next j
    if m > 29 then
        ' ...
    End If
Next j
```

Comment: For my purposes, this code ended up being slightly more functional than the other. Thank you for the suggestion Jeeped. This ended up working easily! Great logic trick.

Answer (score 2):

Do your loop and if False is found then record that in a Boolean.

Test the Boolean and do the code if none were found:

```
Dim fndflse As Boolean
fndflse = False
For m = 2 To 29
    If Worksheets("Current Content Analysis").Cells(contentrownum, contentcolnum) = False And _
    (Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(keywordrownum, m) = Worksheets("Product Categorization").Cells(productrownum, (m + 1)) Or _
    Worksheets("Keyword Categorization").Cells(keywordrownum, m) = "All") Then
        fndflse = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next m
If Not fndflse Then
    'your code it all true
End If
```

Comment: Although, I think the OP may need to edit your answer a bit if they only want to skip the next portion if **all** of the of the test results are true. If I'm reading your code correctly, it'll skip the next portion if **any** of the test results are true.

Comment: If they all are true then `fndflse` will be `False` and the `Not fndflse` will return `True` and as such the code will run.  If any are `False` then the for shortcircuits and `fndflse` will be `True` and the `Not fndflse` will return `False` and as such the code will not run. As per my understanding of the requirements.

Comment: I added this in to the code and got a mismatch error on the "Exit For" line.
Will the exit for line only execute when the results of the If statement are false?

Comment: Forgot the `End IF` @Dys_Lexi_A

Comment: I think the logic is backwards; I understood it that if the three conditions matched then Next m, not Exit For. I had to reverse the OP's logic to use Exit For.

Comment: @Jeeped maybe, I did not scrutinize the logic of the If statement.  Just added the loop logic, be that as it may, yours is less typing, once again.

Comment: Let the OP decide; the boolean method is sound in all other regards.

Comment: Agreed that the boolean method is sound. This works but was a bit more difficult to understand with a quick read due to the True/False and "not" statements. After changing a few of the boolean rules, I was able to get this to work as well.
I am not certain whether this answer or the other answer is more "efficient". I am still learning more about efficiencies when it comes to code in general.
Since I share this macro with others, I selected the other code suggestion because my colleagues will likely find it easier to decipher.
Thank you!

Comment: @Dys_Lexi_A - The only difference is the declaration and assignment of a boolean variable so it is so minuscule as for all intents and purposes to be nothing at all. Just use the one that makes more sense to you.